# Enthought canopy: importing files

Tags: directory, enthought, canopy

I'm trying to read a file but I keep receiving a IOError: file not in directory. I have not touched the directory for Canopy at all since install and I'm not exactly sure where to put a file so my program in Canopy can read it.

Thank you in advanced.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This question is not answerable without knowing what file you are trying to read, what is your current directory, where you are running the code (terminal ipython, Canopy GUI, etc).

That said, and hopefully addressing your final comment, the default directory in Canopy python is your "user home" directory. You can see where that is (or change it) by looking in the upper right corner of your Canopy Python pane.

Comment: Hi Jonathan, thank you for your answer. I have found the working directory and can read it from the Canopy GUI.